# Table border in Google Docs API

Tags: border, google-docs-api

I'm looking for a way to get the border width of a Google Docs using the API?

I have setup a test document that has two 1-cell tables.
First one with default borders and the second one with 0-width borders and a third one with 3 pt border.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KOiw6bmsNhdOGGr9OZDWHNHrEID5RZncyCRRFFSU_Ok/edit

I retrieve the document using the [get request](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get)

I can't find any difference between the three tables in terms of border width.

According to the [documentation TableCellStyle](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#tablecellstyle) should have borderTop/Bottom/Left/Right values but I'm not sure what I need to do to have them included in the response.

All 3 tableCellStyle looks the same, like this:

```
              "tableCellStyle": {
                "rowSpan": 1,
                "columnSpan": 1,
                "backgroundColor": {},
                "paddingLeft": {
                  "magnitude": 5,
                  "unit": "PT"
                },
                "paddingRight": {
                  "magnitude": 5,
                  "unit": "PT"
                },
                "paddingTop": {
                  "magnitude": 5,
                  "unit": "PT"
                },
                "paddingBottom": {
                  "magnitude": 5,
                  "unit": "PT"
                },
                "contentAlignment": "TOP"
              }
```

Each table cell contain a paragraph with a the same paragraphstyle:

```
                      "borderLeft": {
                        "color": {},
                        "width": {
                          "unit": "PT"
                        },
                        "padding": {
                          "unit": "PT"
                        },
                        "dashStyle": "SOLID"
                      },
```

**Update**

I was setting the table border in the above example which is not represented in the API response.
My assumption was that the table border was reflected in the cells in the response data since there was no property for the table border itself. Which is partly correct, see answers.

Comment: Can you provide a sample Document for replicating your situation? I would like to confirm it. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation from your replying. So I cannot think of the issue and solution. I apologize for this. But I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Comment: @Tanaike I've updated the question with a shared docment. I don't get the differences as you get, I also tried modifying the document, from 0 to 3 pt border but the only change recorded in the response was the descriptive text I changed inside the cell.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. I could confirm about your situation. At Google API, when the value is `0`, there is the case that the property is not shown. For example, this can be seen at Sheets API. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51226995/7108653) This might be the current specification. I think that about the border width of `0`, this is the reason of `"width": {"unit": "PT"},`. About the border widths of `1` and `3`, I could replicate your issue. I think that this might be a bug. Docs API is growing now. So this might be resolved in the future.

Comment: So as the current workaround, how about modifying the border color? When the border color is changed, the border widths of `1` and `3` can be included in the response value from Docs API. About this issue, I think that this might be related to above situation. Because the default border color is the black which has `0, 0, 0` for red, green and blue, respectively. By this, `rgbColor` of the border color has no properties.

Comment: But I'm not sure whether my speculation is correct. I think that in this case, how about reporting this issue to [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)? If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [TableCellStyle documentation](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#tablecellstyle):

> Inherited table cell styles are represented as unset fields in this message. A table cell style can inherit from the table's style.

In this case, TableCellStyle inherits the default borderLeft, borderRight, borderTop and borderBottom with the default style, the representation of which would look as follows:

```js
"borderTop": {
  "color": {
    "color": {
      "rgbColor": {}
    }
  },
  "width": {
    "magnitude": 1,
    "unit": "PT"
  },
  "dashStyle": "SOLID"
}
```

Essentially, if you are trying to obtain the borders width, you would have to firstly check whether that border field exists in your data. If it doesn't, you would set the default value to it (`1 PT`). As an example, using JavaScript with its [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```js
var borderTopMagnitude = tableCellStyle.borderTop ? tableCellStyle.borderTop.width.magnitude : 1;
var borderBottomMagnitude = tableCellStyle.borderBottom ? tableCellStyle.borderBottom.width.magnitude : 1;
var borderLeftMagnitude = tableCellStyle.borderLeft ? tableCellStyle.borderLeft.width.magnitude : 1;
var borderRightMagnitude = tableCellStyle.borderRight ? tableCellStyle.borderRight.width.magnitude : 1;
```

Comment: ´TableStyle´ only have one property documented, ´tableColumnProperties´.
Looking at the document/response there is no relevant properties to be inherited. The only mention of ´magnitude´ are for font sizes.

Comment: Where did you find the default style?
Only one of the two tables use default cell style, the other should have some overriding properties?

Comment: @hultqvist In case you modify the border's width to anything other than 1, yes, it is overridden (also by changing its default color or dash style). The default style can be inferred by manually creating the elements in Docs either using the API or the UI (there is no documentation about it). Cheers

Comment: @hultqvist [here](https://www.diffchecker.com/PxLuz1cE) you can see the difference between a 0pt border table (left) and 1pt border table (right). On the left, borderTop, etc. are defined, but their `width` attribute are set to `{"unit": "PT"}` (notice it is not specifying the magnitude - which is defaulted to `0`). On the right, borderTop, etc. are NOT defined, and the default borders are used instead (which have a width of 1PT). I hope that makes sense. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, there is a bug in the google Document API. I found a bug report: (https://issuetracker.google.com/186012454)

I produced a [document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11AEkqC7RxMTqV4sAT4KDVTsHcierakHWdrCbMPi8jtA): there I increased the width and the color of the table borders.

The TableCellStyle element of the left top cell is nil.
The border properties of the Content.Paragraph elements linked with the table cell are also nil.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a new table the following applies in order.

1. Changing table border styles won't reflect in the API response.
2. Changes in individual cells, or all cells at once, will be reflected in the API response.
3. Once step 2 is performed, changes in table border style will now be reflected in the API response, but only for the cells that have been modified individually previously.